# Optimization with Mathematica: Use BinCounts in Objective Function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization

Using Mathematica, I need to optimize a function that is defined in terms of `BinCounts`; 
the arguments that I want to maximize over define the bin cutpoints.

I think the problem is that Mathematica expands the objective function 
in terms of the arguments before they have been given numerical 
values, so `BinCounts` complains that the bin specification is not "a 
list containing real values, Infinity, and -Infinity".

I think the following is a minimal example of the kind of thing I'm 
trying to do and what's happening. I'd be very grateful for advice on 
how to address this problem.

```
In[1]:= data = RandomReal[1, 30]; (* Make some test data. *)

In[2]:= f[a_, b_, c_] := BinCounts[data, {{0, a, b, c, 1}}] (* Shorthand to use below… *)

In[12]:= g[a_, b_, c_] := Max[f[a, b, c]] - Min[f[a, b, c]] (* Objective function. *)

In[13]:= NMaximize[{g[a, b, c], 0 < a < b < c < 1}, {a, b, c}] (* Try to oprimize. *)

During evaluation of In[13]:= BinCounts::cvals: The bin specification {{0,a,b,c,1}} is not a list containing real values, Infinity, and -Infinity. >>

During evaluation of In[13]:= BinCounts::cvals: The bin specification {{0,a,b,c,1}} is not a list containing real values, Infinity, and -Infinity. >>

During evaluation of In[13]:= BinCounts::cvals: The bin specification {{0,a,b,c,1}} is not a list containing real values, Infinity, and -Infinity. >>

During evaluation of In[13]:= General::stop: Further output of BinCounts::cvals will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

Out[13]= {0., {a -> 0., b -> 0., c -> 1.}}
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution is simply to specify that the objective function is defined only in terms of numerical arguments, like so:

```
g[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := Max[f[a, b, c]] - Min[f[a, b, c]]
```